# MvvmCross Android Dialog - behaviour of nested RootElements

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm confused about the capabilities of the MvvmCross Dialog builder code.

I have a SettingsView that inherits from BaseSettingsView.

The following code, on iOS, shows a dialog with a single section. When that section is clicked on, this produces another panel which has the section in the RootElement:

```
Root = new RootElement("Settings")
{
    new Section()
    {
        (Element) new RootElement("Location Settings")
                                  {
                                      new Section("Details")
                                          {
                                              new EntryElement("Name", "Location Name"),
                                          },
                                  },
                           }
                   };
```

However, on Android, with a SettingsView that has exactly the same code, when the section is clicked on, no other panel or view appears. I am wondering whether it is possible to have this sort of "nested view" on Android, or whether I should be creating a click handler for this entry, which will show an entirely new dialog via navigation to another ViewModel.

Interesting, the following code will produce an element that when clicked on will create a brand new dialog that has the entry in the nested RootElement inside of it. However, this only seems to work for RadioGroups as far as I can tell?

```
Root = new RootElement("Settings")
        {
            new Section()
                {
            (Element) new RootElement("Status", new RadioGroup(0))
                            {
                                new Section("Status")
                                    {
                                        new RadioElement("On"),
                                        new RadioElement("Off"),
                                    },
                            },
                },
```

I have looked at the Mvx Dialog example and viewed the N+1 but cannot find any guidance on whether this sort of automatic navigation to nested RootElements is possible or desirable with MvvmCross on Android.

Thanks,

Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is inherited MonoDroid.Dialog - from https://github.com/kevinmcmahon/MonoDroid.Dialog/tree/lastsnapshot

> Interesting, the following code will produce an element that when clicked on will create a brand new dialog that has the entry in the nested RootElement inside of it. However, this only seems to work for RadioGroups as far as I can tell?

I don't think this is correct - I think RadioGroups show Android popup `Dialog`s to enable selection - see implementation at https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossUI/CrossUI.Droid/Dialog/Elements/RootElement.cs#L327

There is also a recent code contribution in this area in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/392 - but I've not personally looked at this yet.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. To summarise as I understand it: The pop-up is only built in for RadioGroup on Droid. Nested RootElements on iOS give automatic navigation to another screen with the elements under that RootElement. Therefore, to support settings sub-screens when you click on an element, I'm best off firing off a ShowViewModel<> call or otherwise creating a new dialog for the desired submenu.

Comment: There's nothing built-in - which was probably because Dialog was built on top of Activities which operate in a different memory/lifecycle model to UIViewControllers. But I suspect you could build something fairly quickly (a day?)  if you wanted to - especially if you looked at fragments or at some of the linearlayout work that other have done recently. Not trying to avoid the question - what you're "best off" doing really depends on what the app needs and how much time you have.

Comment: Is it possible to host the element builder code inside of a fragment instead of a dialogactivity? Ideally (and this would help facilitate animations) I'd like to have the different settings pages as fragments inside a dialog or activity. Otherwise I when I opened the settings sub-page I guess I'd need to load a new dialog for each page - which is doable but not as neat

Comment: A policeman once told me that "bikes can go anywhere". I believe the same is true of code. "especially if you looked at fragments or at some of the linearlayout work that other have done recently." - that may help you

Comment: So it's possible but not out of the box. I'll have a think about whether I have time to put mountain bike tires on my road bike ;-) Cheers for your help.